# Global Variable not Updating

Tags: ios, variables, swift

I've got a global variable that I'm trying to update in one class and then pass to another class to update a UITableview.

The first class looks like this:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    var distance: Float = 0.0

    //Called once a second
    func updateLocation() {
        if let mylocation = mapView.myLocation {
            self.distance += Distance(self.lastLocation, Coordinate2: mylocation.coordinate)
            println(self.distance)
            self.lastLocation = mylocation.coordinate
        }
    }
    func fetchValues(instrument: String) -> AnyObject {
        if instrument == "Distance" {
            return self.distance
        }
        else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

In my second class I have the following:

```
class StatusViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: StatusCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as StatusCell
        let value = MapViewController()
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            var distance: Float = Float(value.fetchValues("Distance") as NSNumber)/1.852
            cell.InstrumentValue.text = distance.description + " Nm"
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        TableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The function is called every time I open the tab as I intended but for some reason the first class passes 0.0 every time, even after my updateLocation() function correctly updates distance and prints it to Xcode. What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no global variables in this story. `distance` in the first file is a property - an instance variable. You can only get the particular value of a particular instance of this class (MapViewController). There can be many MapViewController instances, each with a different `distance`.

You are saying `value.fetchValues`, but what is `value` exactly? I have no reason to believe that `value` is the correct instance here. And the fact that you are having this problem suggests that it is not. How are you obtaining `value`?

For example, if you are instantiating a new MapViewController, then of course *its* `distance` is the default, `0` - it is not the same MapViewController whose `distance` is being updated.

**EDIT** Now you have edited your question to reveal that you are saying:

```
    let value = MapViewController()
```

It is just as I had guessed. There's your problem.

Comment: But in the second file I'm declaring the distance variable to have the same value as the global variable found in the first by calling the fetchValues() function. Is that not right?

Comment: Apologies. Updated and corrected. - Next time please copy and paste and format your code correctly. Your current code was illegibly formatted, and would not compile; I had to change it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I omitted the initialization of the instance by accident I've edited the above code to reflect `let value = MapViewController()` How could I create an instance that always matches the `distance` of the first file?

Comment: It might help you to stop and learn what classes and instances are. You clearly have no idea what object-oriented programming is, since you seem to imagine that `MapViewController()` is the same MapViewController that is being updated - and of course it isn't.

Comment: You must not create _any_ instance. The instance already exists. Your problem is to _refer_ to it.

Comment: The problem of getting a reference to another existing instance is so interesting that my book devotes several pages to it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_visibility_by_relationship

Comment: So from what I understand from the linked chapter I should be able to pass variables between my tabs by referencing the parent UITabBarCobtroller?

Comment: Absolutely! If these are both view controller children of a tab bar controller, you can go up to the tab bar controller and down to another child. You will also have to cast, because the child will not automatically be known to be a MapViewController.

Comment: So I'm imagining I should use something like this: `cell.InstrumentValue.text = presentingViewController?.MapViewController.distance` but this is obviously the improper syntax. How do you call an adjacent ViewController? P.S. Thank you so much for taking the time to walk me through this!

Comment: Wait - is it the presenting view controller or the parent tab bar controller? Make up your mind! Those are totally different things.

Comment: Well I have a UITabBarController that is the parent view controller I believe with both the MapViewController and StatusViewController as tabs within the parent UITabBarController and I'm trying to pass my variable from MapViewController to StatusViewController.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68093/discussion-between-matt-and-user3185748).

Answer (score 0):

a solution to your problem could be to make a variable in the AppDelegate.swift file and access that from both of your ViewControllers.

in the AppDelegate:

```
var distance : Float = 0.0
```

and in the two ViewControllers you make this variable that represents the instance of the AppDelegate. You can do this with the AppDelegate because there can only be one and only one instance of this class. You can not do that with ViewController classes as you have tried to do. I will recomment that you do as matt also said and study what classes and instances are, but anyway.. write this in both of the ViewControllers

```
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
```

and when you need the distance value you simply write

```
appDelegate.distance
```

example:

```
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
func updateLocation() {
    if let mylocation = mapView.myLocation {
        appDelegate.distance += Distance(self.lastLocation, Coordinate2: mylocation.coordinate)
        println(self.distance)
        self.lastLocation = mylocation.coordinate
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out another solution with Matt's help. Thank you for the input though!